# Plotting histogram from dictionary Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dictionary with one value associated to each key.

I would like to plot this dictionary as a bar chart with `matplotlib`, set a different color for each bar, and find a way to use long strings as legible labels.

```
X = np.arange(len(dictionay))
pl.bar(X, dictionay.values(), align='center', width=0.5)
pl.xticks(X, dictionay.keys())
pl.xticks(rotation=20)
ymax = max(dictionay.values()) + 1
pl.ylim(0, ymax)
pl.show()
```

The result:

[image: Ugly graph showing undesired behavior]

My keys are very long so we don't see anything clearly! And in addition it would be great to have this plot sorted by y values. I know a dictionary can't be sorted so may I go through a list?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want the keys to be sorted? Do you really need the full length of each one?

Comment: what is your question? it seems like your doing it? is your question "How Do I use shorter keys in my dictionary?" I dont understand ... you can certainly give a sorted list...

Comment: Two possibilities are: 1) how about plotting the string vertically in the whitespace beside the bar, 2) having the string as a pop-up when one hovers the mouse pointer on the bar. Would either of these work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to plot this dictionnay with matplotlib, set a different
>   color for each key and find a way to plot the key which is a long
>   string ... And in addition it would be great to have this plot sorted.

Unfortunately the best way I was able to graph long strings was to truncate them.  I arbitrarily chose 15 characters as the maximum length, you can use any length you find appropriate.

The following code defines a dictionary (`Dictionary`), creates a list of sorted keys and sorted values by value from largest to smallest, and truncates keys that are too long to display well. When the bar plot is graphed, it is done one bar at a time so it can set an individual color to the bar.  The color is chosen by iterating through the tuple defined at the beginning (Colors).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Dictionary = {"A":3,"C":5,"B":2,"D":3,"E":4,
              "A very long key that will be truncated when it is graphed":1}
Dictionary_Length = len(Dictionary)
Max_Key_Length = 15
Sorted_Dict_Values = sorted(Dictionary.values(), reverse=True)
Sorted_Dict_Keys = sorted(Dictionary, key=Dictionary.get, reverse=True)
for i in range(0,Dictionary_Length):
    Key = Sorted_Dict_Keys[i]
    Key = Key[:Max_Key_Length]
    Sorted_Dict_Keys[i] = Key
X = np.arange(Dictionary_Length)
Colors = ('b','g','r','c')  # blue, green, red, cyan

Figure = plt.figure()
Axis = Figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
for i in range(0,Dictionary_Length):
    Axis.bar(X[i], Sorted_Dict_Values[i], align='center',width=0.5, color=Colors[i%len(Colors)])

Axis.set_xticks(X)
xtickNames = Axis.set_xticklabels(Sorted_Dict_Keys)
plt.setp(Sorted_Dict_Keys)
plt.xticks(rotation=20)
ymax = max(Sorted_Dict_Values) + 1
plt.ylim(0,ymax)

plt.show()
```

Output graph:

[image: Output Graph]